# Lightning Data Service support in Lightning Out

Tags: lightning-out, lightning-data-service

I am currently working on developing a new Lightning application and wanted to use Lightning Data Service. However I see from the Dev Guide (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.210.0.lightning.meta/lightning/data_service_considerations.htm) that Lightning Data Service is not supported in Lightning Out or in Communities. To me this seems like a big issue as I know some of our customers are reluctant to switch over to full Lightning Experience so we would probably need to support Lightning Out. We also have a need to work in Communities.

Does anyone know if this will be supported in upcoming releases?